# setState Is not Working Inside setInterval In React

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, reactjs

When I click on my button that is calling the _handlePressStartStop() function, I get an error about setState. It tells :

```
 **(intermediate value).bind is not a function**
```

I know I've got trouble with ***this***, maybe it the source of my problem. Here is my code:

```
class StopWatch extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    startTime: null,
    timeElapsed: null
  };
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <View style={styles.counter}>
          <Text style={styles.counterText}>{this.state.timeElapsed}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonsWrapper}>
          <Button buttonType='startStop' onPress={this._handlePressStartStop}>Start</Button>
          <Button buttonType='lap' onPress={this._handlePressLap}>Lap</Button>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.footer}>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

_handlePressStartStop() {
  console.log("press start");

  let startTime = new Date();

  setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        timeElapsed: new Date() - startTime
      }.bind(this))
  }, 1000);

}

_handlePressLap() {
  console.log("press lap");
}
```

}

Comment: Objects don't have a `.bind` method. That's what the error is telling you. `{...}.bind(this)` is simply invalid.

Comment: Related: [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you wouldnt want to bind to this like that. You're binding the object to this which is invalid. How about you bind the handler

`onPress={this._handlePressStartStop}.bind(this)` instead?

this way, everything executed inside the handler function will have the same `this` (a react component instance)

Comment: Thanks, it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`this._handlePressStartStop.bind(this)`